# why can't I override Math.PI but can override Math.floor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I tried assigning `Math.PI` to `1000000`, but when trying to use the value, I still got the default non-overridden value, while I was able to override `Math.floor` with `function(){console.log('floor')}` and calling it called the overridden function. I was wondering why that is and how I'd be able to override `Math.PI`.  I tried this on both node v14 and Chrome v83.

Comment: [`Math.PI` is non writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI). To override `Math.PI`, you would need to override `Math`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Math.PI descriptor using Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(), and you'll see that this property in not writable. That is why when you try to reassign its value, it is not being updated

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Math, 'PI'))
```

Comment: And it will throw a TypeError in *strict mode*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite `Math.PI` as suggested in the below image from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can not be override because `Math.PI` is created using:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: 'static'
});
```

writable inside descriptor is set to be as false.

eg -

```
Object.defineProperty(company, name,{value: "Sapient", writable: false, })
```

now if you try to change as `company.name ="Mindtree"` it will get ignored but if you make writeable as true then it will get reflected.